# Protect non-empty cells VBA

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, error-messaging

I've added VBA code which will insert either the time or date to a cell upon double clicking. I managed to get that going pretty well.

The bit I'm struggling with is getting the cell to protect and lock after the time/date has been entered.

I've got to a point where when I double click/try to edit a non-empty cell, I get a runtime error. Upon debugging, the line that throws me up is `"Target.Formula = Format(Now, "ttttt")"`.

I'm also not able to throw an error message either.

I'm so close!

Any advice would be truly appreciated!

My code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:E")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Formula = Format(Now, "ttttt")
      End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Formula = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")

      End If


End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("A:A,C:E"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
    xRg.Locked = True
    Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="123"

   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "Cell already filled"

   Resume Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try `Target = Format(Now, "ttttt")` instead of `Target.Formula ...`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response @Vityata!
I just tried that and I get the same debug error on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that the sheet is locked until some change happens on the worksheet, so if you remove the `Worksheet_Change` event and have your code as follows then it should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="123"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:E")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Cancel = True
            Target.Formula = Format(Now(), "ttttt")
        End If
      End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Cancel = True
            Target.Formula = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        End If
    End If
Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="123"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Xabier, thanks for the response! The goal is to lock the cell once the date or time has been entered. After trying your code, I'm stall able to change the cell which is filled with date or time

Comment: @AnnaPage I've just updated my response, it will not let you add data to a cell which has already got some data in it...

Comment: I got an error message on my first run, but after that I could edit cells freely as before. 
Thank you for your support!

Comment: The first line @Xabier? 
`Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)`

Comment: What error are you getting? I have tried and tested the above, and I get no errors, only a prompt when trying to edit any cell as the worksheet is protected...

Comment: I've copied the code above exactly, I don't get an error anymore, but I am able to still alter the non-empty cells @Xabier

Comment: How are you altering the non-empty cells? As the code has the line `If Target.Value = "" Then` so it will only add the date or time if the cell is empty to begin with...

Comment: So it won't add the current time or date, but I can override the time in the cell. I'm looking to lock it completely so the time cannot be overridden - otherwise your code works perfectly @Xabier

Comment: The code as it stands will enter the date or time in the given cell if the cell is empty when you click on it, but it won't add anything if it already has data in it, everything else is locked and cannot be over-ridden, I'm not sure how you are altering the data in the cells, as when I'm testing I'm not able to edit if it has data in it...

Comment: I'm going to test it on a different laptop. I'm able to change the cells which have time in for anything - be it text or altering the actual time

Comment: @AnnaPage, do you have any other code which un-protects the sheet? In my example the sheet is protected unless the cell you double-click on is within the given Range and only if the cell was empty will it write the date/time... I'm guessing you have some code unprotecting the sheet and that's why you are able to alter the contents...

Comment: I haven't any other code but the one you suggested above. 
I've tried it on another laptop and it works perfectly well. I'm going to just start a new workbook in the hope that I can get it to work on my laptop. 

Thank you SO much for your help. I really really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Protect your worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) once with the UserInterfaceOnly:=True parameter and you won't have to unprotect/protect to alter cell contents with VBA.

```
sub protectOnce()
    worksheets("sheet1").unprotect password:="123"
    worksheets("sheet1").protect password:="123", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Jeeped
Do I add this at the beginning or end of my code?

Comment: You run it by itself once and remove all of the protect/unprotect functions from all other vba code.