# Macro throwing error at protect

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a macro to operate by calling out another macro to unlock a worksheet to allow a RFID reader to scan and input data and then protect the document again to allow it from being edited.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' call another macro
 Call UnProtect
' End Sub
' Dim i As Integer
' MsgBox (Target.Row & ":" & Target.Column)

' For i = 8 To 200
If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row <= 12 Then
  If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value <> "" And Cells(Target.Row, "E").Value = "" Then

    ' Cells(Target.Row, "E").Value = Now()
    ' Cells(Target.Row, "E").NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
  End If
End If
' Next
' Range("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
' End Sub

' Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Dim i As Integer
' MsgBox (Target.Row & ":" & Target.Column)

' For i = 8 To 200
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row <= 17 Then
  If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value <> "" And Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value = "" Then

    Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value = Now()
    ' Cells(Target.Row, "F").NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
  End If
End If
' Next
' Range("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
' End Sub

' Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Dim i As Integer
' MsgBox (Target.Row & ":" & Target.Column)

' For i = 8 To 200
If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row >= 15 Then
  If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value <> "" And Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value = "" Then
        Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value = Now()
        Cells(Target.Row, "D").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyy"
  End If
End If
' Next
Range("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
' End Sub
' call another macro
    Call Protect
End Sub
```

The two macros it is calling to are

```
Sub UnProtect()
'Unprotect a worksheet
Sheets("Sign in Sheet").UnProtect
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Protect()
'Protect a worksheet
Sheets("Sign in Sheet").Protect
End Sub
```

However, when I only include the unlock macro, the code will work fine.  But when I add the protect macro, an error code will come up

Run-Time Error '1004':
Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class

and it points to

```
Cells(Target.Row, "D").NumberFormat  = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Any ideas as to what exactly is happening.

Comment: Have you considered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747702/protect-non-empty-cells-vba/48748128#48748128)?

Comment: I see no provision for a case when Target is more than a single cell and there's a pretty good chance that the Worksheet_Change is trying to run on top of itself.

Comment: @jeeped that works great, thank you.  Does it have to run every time the document is opened and with this can I allow for a range to be edited even if it is protected.

Comment: a) No, you only protect it once with the UserInterfaceOnly:=true argument although if you ever unprotect it for some reason then you need to protect it again with the UserInterfaceOnly:=true argument. b) That's what the cells Locked property is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no provision for a case when Target is more than a single cell and there's a pretty good chance that the Worksheet_Change is trying to run on top of itself.

Cycle through each range object in Target and disable event triggers.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo safe_exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Call Unprotect
    Dim t As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A17")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A17"))
            If t.Value <> vbNullString And t.Offset(0, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then
                t.Offset(0, 1) = Now
                t.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
            End If
        Next t
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C12")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C12"))
            If t.Value <> vbNullString And t.Offset(0, 2).Value <> vbNullString Then
                t.Offset(0, 2) = Now
                t.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
            End If
        Next t
        'I don't understand why column F comes into play here
        ' Range("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C15:C999999")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("C15:C999999"))
            If t.Value <> vbNullString And t.Offset(0, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then
                t.Offset(0, 1) = Now
                t.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyy"
            End If
        Next t
        Range("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If

    Call Protect
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```